# Seeking frameworks for creating Android application with custom map for offline GIS work

Tags: android, maps, gis

I need to create an Android application for offline work with a custom map that would be able to display raster and vector layers using data from local device storage. Also features to draw, edit, remove and measure geometries are needed. Also being able to work with non WGS 84 projections is desired since all the data is in EPSG:3346.

I have been using OpenLayers for a web based custom map so I guess I could say I am looking for OpenLayers but for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You could get most of your desired features using the Avenza Maps app. At the Pro subscription level you can load your own raster layers as well as shapefiles. You can draw and measure. I'm not sure if you can edit or remove geometries, though.
At the basic (free) level, you can add up to three raster maps and unlimited vector layers in KML format.